# Showing an image using c++

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I've written this code for showing an image in c++.

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int x,char*y) 
{
    string Image_Name = y[1];


    Mat image=imread(Image_Name);


    if (image.empty())
    {
        cout << "This is invalid input" << endl;
        return -1; 
    }

    namedWindow("Lenna", WINDOW_NORMAL);

    imshow("Lenna",image);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;

}
```

When I try to run it ,Compiler shows me these errors :

> "Severity Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'char' to
>   'std::basic_string,std::allocator>' OpencvTest  e:\programming
>   c\showing an image\opencvtest\source.cpp  12 "

and :

> "Severity Code    Description Project File    Line Error (active)     no
>   suitable constructor exists to convert from "char" to
>   "std::basic_string,
>   std::allocator>"    OpencvTest  e:\programming C\Showing an
>   image\OpencvTest\Source.cpp   12"

Can anyone help me with this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor mistake:

```
int main(int x,char*y)
```

Should read

```
int main(int x, char*y[])
```

or

```
int main(int x, char **y)
```

There is no constructor to convert from a `char` to `std::string` indeed, only from a `char*` or a `char` and an integer count.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string for reference.

Also, there are standard names for those 2 arguments: `argc` - Argument Count and `argv` - Argument Values. Better stick to the standard.

You also need to check if `argc` equals 2, otherwise there is no second argument to read from.

Edit: It makes more sense to check for `argc >= 2` rather than strictly `argc == 2`, in that case the program is going to ignore the arguments following the second one.

Comment: Thanks for your good answer. And there is only one problem i have with your answer : Why should i check if "argc" equals 2 ? Becuase if i dont use if loop for checking ,there is no problem with my code and it runs successfully.

Comment: If is usually called a "statement", since it does not recur, in contrast to a loop. The point of checking for `argc == 2` is to ensure there are 2 arguments: the first argument is always the executable name (e.g. "a.out" or "main.exe" -  I don't know how Visual Studio names the resulting executable file) and the second argument is the image name. If there are fewer arguments, then the program will still read the data at argv[1], but it's going to be garbage or may crash the program with access out of bounds.